# Problems with querying nested collection

Tags: ravendb

I'm just starting with RavenDb.
I would like to model train time table. Each train is described like this in real world.

```
Train no: 123
Reda      07:00
Gdynia    07:30
Sopot     08:00

Train no: 555
Reda      08:00
Gdynia    08:30
Sopot     09:00

Train no: 666
Reda      08:00
Wejherowo 09:00
```

I would like to query for trains that visit station A (not necessary start from that station) and then go to station B (don't have to finish it's run there) and not departing from station A earlier then 08:00. So for timetable above if I ask for train from `Reda` to `Gdynia` at 08:00 I get train no 555. Same If I ask for train from `Reda` to `Sopot` at 08:00. But I should not receive train 666.

I modeled it like this in code.

```cs
public class Train
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Station> Stations { get; set; }

    public Train()
    {
        Stations = new List<Station>();
    }
}

public class Station
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DepartFrom { get; set; }    
}
```

My first attempt to query it was this:

```cs
using (var documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080" })
{
    documentStore.Initialize();
    var session = documentStore.OpenSession();

    var found = from train in session.Query<Train>()
                     where train.Stations.Any(s => s.Name == from)
                        && train.Stations.Any(s => s.Name == to)
                     select train;
}
```

But the && doesn't work with nested collections. I found out that only || works and that is because of how Lucene works. I have also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121061/finding-objects-which-contains-at-least-all-elements-from-subset-using-ravendb-a) that there is Intersect method that should allow me to create query I want but I cannot find that extension method anywhere (I'm using RavenDB Stable v1.0 build 992). What is the way to do it and do I have to create Index? How should it look?

Comment: Add `Raven.Client.Linq` to your using statements to get the `.Intersect()` extension method.  I will research the rest of your question and post an answer shortly.

Comment: Question - do trains run over midnight?  Would it be possible that a train arrives at a later time with an earlier number? (depart 23:00, arrive 01:00)  and if so, how do you plan to record that?  A "next day" flag?  Or an artificial time like 25:00?  And are you concerned about time zones being different?

Comment: Yes it's possible for train to start at 23:00 and arrive at last station at 01:00. I didn't think about that. But I think it will be enough if I just add stations in correct order and then display them in that order. But now I'm wondering how to check that 'from' station is really 'from' station and not 'to' station. Query above will only check if train visits both stations. It doesn't check order in which it visits them.

Comment: Can you rely on the order being maintained?  If 01:00 comes after 23:00 then infer that it means "on the next day"?  And what about time zones?  Are the times local to each station?  Then the order is really important, but how do you align it for your query?  In other words, you say "earlier than 8:00" in your post, but you probably mean "earlier than 8:00 at that particular location"

Comment: I have no other idea how to organize it differently. Yes if 01:00 comes after 23:00 it means another day. All stations are in the same timezone. When I say I want train from station A to station B at 08:00 it means that that train has to depart from station A at 08:00 or later.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I watched your presentation earlier this week, on Dates and Times .. What if .. your train station is in Brazil, and the 23:00 is an hour late, on a DST changeover. Is it an hour late, or 2 hours late? Try explaining that to a customer ... ;-)

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz - It's still one hour late. Even if the arrival time is 01:00. :)  But thanks for reminding me about this question. Looks like I never got to posting a response!